# Remove space between cat()

Tags: r

Here's a simple one:

```
a <- "a"
cat(a,"b")


"a b"
```

Why is there a whitespace between them?
How to remove it so it come out like this:

```
"ab"
```

Comment: Try `cat(a, "b", sep = "")`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can also try this one

```
cat(paste0(a, "b"))
```